# What do these error messages mean and how to fix it?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, linux-kernel

==============================================================

actually I figured out this is an issue of intel video driver:http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0902.3/01703.html

==============================================================

I am using ubuntu 10.0.4 TLS, and this is my main board info: http://www.made-in-china.com/showroom/geshem/product-detailbqfJOksvrXcn/China-Mainboard-ITX-WN45A-D.html

These error messages were from /var/log/messages

```
Dec 17 09:46:53 my-desktop kernel: [ 1080.890084] i915          D 0000000000000000     0   595      2 0x00000000
Dec 17 09:46:53 my-desktop kernel: [ 1080.890096]  ffff880030257d40 0000000000000046 0000000000015bc0 0000000000015bc0
Dec 17 09:46:53 my-desktop kernel: [ 1080.890107]  ffff880030b53178 ffff880030257fd8 0000000000015bc0 ffff880030b52dc0
Dec 17 09:46:53 my-desktop kernel: [ 1080.890117]  0000000000015bc0 ffff880030257fd8 0000000000015bc0 ffff880030b53178
Dec 17 09:46:53 my-desktop kernel: [ 1080.890127] Call Trace:
Dec 17 09:46:53 my-desktop kernel: [ 1080.890148]  [<ffffffff81542907>] __mutex_lock_slowpath+0xf7/0x180
Dec 17 09:46:53 my-desktop kernel: [ 1080.890161]  [<ffffffff810578b0>] ? finish_task_switch+0x50/0xe0
Dec 17 09:46:53 my-desktop kernel: [ 1080.890169]  [<ffffffff815427eb>] mutex_lock+0x2b/0x50
Dec 17 09:46:53 my-desktop kernel: [ 1080.890207]  [<ffffffffa0110add>] i915_gem_retire_work_handler+0x3d/0xa0 [i915]
Dec 17 09:46:53 my-desktop kernel: [ 1080.890231]  [<ffffffffa0110aa0>] ? i915_gem_retire_work_handler+0x0/0xa0 [i915]
Dec 17 09:46:53 my-desktop kernel: [ 1080.890243]  [<ffffffff8107f9a7>] run_workqueue+0xc7/0x1a0
Dec 17 09:46:53 my-desktop kernel: [ 1080.890252]  [<ffffffff8107fb23>] worker_thread+0xa3/0x110
Dec 17 09:46:53 my-desktop kernel: [ 1080.890261]  [<ffffffff81084570>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x40
Dec 17 09:46:53 my-desktop kernel: [ 1080.890270]  [<ffffffff8107fa80>] ? worker_thread+0x0/0x110
Dec 17 09:46:53 my-desktop kernel: [ 1080.890278]  [<ffffffff810841f6>] kthread+0x96/0xa0
Dec 17 09:46:53 my-desktop kernel: [ 1080.890287]  [<ffffffff810131ea>] child_rip+0xa/0x20
Dec 17 09:46:53 my-desktop kernel: [ 1080.890296]  [<ffffffff81084160>] ? kthread+0x0/0xa0
Dec 17 09:46:53 my-desktop kernel: [ 1080.890303]  [<ffffffff810131e0>] ? child_rip+0x0/0x20
Dec 17 10:08:53 my-desktop kernel: [ 2400.890080] i915          D 0000000000000000     0   595      2 0x00000000
Dec 17 10:08:53 my-desktop kernel: [ 2400.890092]  ffff880030257d40 0000000000000046 0000000000015bc0 0000000000015bc0
Dec 17 10:08:53 my-desktop kernel: [ 2400.890103]  ffff880030b53178 ffff880030257fd8 0000000000015bc0 ffff880030b52dc0
Dec 17 10:08:53 my-desktop kernel: [ 2400.890113]  0000000000015bc0 ffff880030257fd8 0000000000015bc0 ffff880030b53178
Dec 17 10:08:53 my-desktop kernel: [ 2400.890122] Call Trace:
Dec 17 10:08:53 my-desktop kernel: [ 2400.890143]  [<ffffffff81542907>] __mutex_lock_slowpath+0xf7/0x180
Dec 17 10:08:53 my-desktop kernel: [ 2400.890156]  [<ffffffff810578b0>] ? finish_task_switch+0x50/0xe0
Dec 17 10:08:53 my-desktop kernel: [ 2400.890164]  [<ffffffff815427eb>] mutex_lock+0x2b/0x50
Dec 17 10:08:53 my-desktop kernel: [ 2400.890202]  [<ffffffffa0110add>] i915_gem_retire_work_handler+0x3d/0xa0 [i915]
Dec 17 10:08:53 my-desktop kernel: [ 2400.890226]  [<ffffffffa0110aa0>] ? i915_gem_retire_work_handler+0x0/0xa0 [i915]
Dec 17 10:08:53 my-desktop kernel: [ 2400.890237]  [<ffffffff8107f9a7>] run_workqueue+0xc7/0x1a0
Dec 17 10:08:53 my-desktop kernel: [ 2400.890246]  [<ffffffff8107fb23>] worker_thread+0xa3/0x110
Dec 17 10:08:53 my-desktop kernel: [ 2400.890256]  [<ffffffff81084570>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x40
Dec 17 10:08:53 my-desktop kernel: [ 2400.890265]  [<ffffffff8107fa80>] ? worker_thread+0x0/0x110
Dec 17 10:08:53 my-desktop kernel: [ 2400.890273]  [<ffffffff810841f6>] kthread+0x96/0xa0
Dec 17 10:08:53 my-desktop kernel: [ 2400.890283]  [<ffffffff810131ea>] child_rip+0xa/0x20
Dec 17 10:08:53 my-desktop kernel: [ 2400.890291]  [<ffffffff81084160>] ? kthread+0x0/0xa0
```

the following are from /var/log/kern.log

```
Dec 17 09:44:53 pujia-desktop kernel: [  960.890068] INFO: task i915:595 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
Dec 17 09:44:53 pujia-desktop kernel: [  960.890076] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
Dec 17 09:44:53 pujia-desktop kernel: [  960.890084] i915          D 0000000000000000     0   595      2 0x00000000
Dec 17 09:44:53 pujia-desktop kernel: [  960.890095]  ffff880030257d40 0000000000000046 0000000000015bc0 0000000000015bc0
Dec 17 09:44:53 pujia-desktop kernel: [  960.890106]  ffff880030b53178 ffff880030257fd8 0000000000015bc0 ffff880030b52dc0
Dec 17 09:44:53 pujia-desktop kernel: [  960.890116]  0000000000015bc0 ffff880030257fd8 0000000000015bc0 ffff880030b53178
Dec 17 09:44:53 pujia-desktop kernel: [  960.890126] Call Trace:
Dec 17 09:44:53 pujia-desktop kernel: [  960.890146]  [<ffffffff81542907>] __mutex_lock_slowpath+0xf7/0x180
Dec 17 09:44:53 pujia-desktop kernel: [  960.890159]  [<ffffffff810578b0>] ? finish_task_switch+0x50/0xe0
Dec 17 09:44:53 pujia-desktop kernel: [  960.890168]  [<ffffffff815427eb>] mutex_lock+0x2b/0x50
Dec 17 09:44:53 pujia-desktop kernel: [  960.890206]  [<ffffffffa0110add>] i915_gem_retire_work_handler+0x3d/0xa0 [i915]
Dec 17 09:44:53 pujia-desktop kernel: [  960.890230]  [<ffffffffa0110aa0>] ? i915_gem_retire_work_handler+0x0/0xa0 [i915]
Dec 17 09:44:53 pujia-desktop kernel: [  960.890241]  [<ffffffff8107f9a7>] run_workqueue+0xc7/0x1a0
Dec 17 09:44:53 pujia-desktop kernel: [  960.890250]  [<ffffffff8107fb23>] worker_thread+0xa3/0x110
Dec 17 09:44:53 pujia-desktop kernel: [  960.890259]  [<ffffffff81084570>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x40
Dec 17 09:44:53 pujia-desktop kernel: [  960.890269]  [<ffffffff8107fa80>] ? worker_thread+0x0/0x110
Dec 17 09:44:53 pujia-desktop kernel: [  960.890276]  [<ffffffff810841f6>] kthread+0x96/0xa0
Dec 17 09:44:53 pujia-desktop kernel: [  960.890286]  [<ffffffff810131ea>] child_rip+0xa/0x20
Dec 17 09:44:53 pujia-desktop kernel: [  960.890294]  [<ffffffff81084160>] ? kthread+0x0/0xa0
Dec 17 09:44:53 pujia-desktop kernel: [  960.890302]  [<ffffffff810131e0>] ? child_rip+0x0/0x20
Dec 17 09:46:53 pujia-desktop kernel: [ 1080.890068] INFO: task i915:595 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
Dec 17 09:46:53 pujia-desktop kernel: [ 1080.890077] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
Dec 17 09:46:53 pujia-desktop kernel: [ 1080.890084] i915          D 0000000000000000     0   595      2 0x00000000
Dec 17 09:46:53 pujia-desktop kernel: [ 1080.890096]  ffff880030257d40 0000000000000046 0000000000015bc0 0000000000015bc0
Dec 17 09:46:53 pujia-desktop kernel: [ 1080.890107]  ffff880030b53178 ffff880030257fd8 0000000000015bc0 ffff880030b52dc0
Dec 17 09:46:53 pujia-desktop kernel: [ 1080.890117]  0000000000015bc0 ffff880030257fd8 0000000000015bc0 ffff880030b53178
Dec 17 09:46:53 pujia-desktop kernel: [ 1080.890127] Call Trace:
Dec 17 09:46:53 pujia-desktop kernel: [ 1080.890148]  [<ffffffff81542907>] __mutex_lock_slowpath+0xf7/0x180
Dec 17 09:46:53 pujia-desktop kernel: [ 1080.890161]  [<ffffffff810578b0>] ? finish_task_switch+0x50/0xe0
Dec 17 09:46:53 pujia-desktop kernel: [ 1080.890169]  [<ffffffff815427eb>] mutex_lock+0x2b/0x50
Dec 17 09:46:53 pujia-desktop kernel: [ 1080.890207]  [<ffffffffa0110add>] i915_gem_retire_work_handler+0x3d/0xa0 [i915]
Dec 17 09:46:53 pujia-desktop kernel: [ 1080.890231]  [<ffffffffa0110aa0>] ? i915_gem_retire_work_handler+0x0/0xa0 [i915]
Dec 17 09:46:53 pujia-desktop kernel: [ 1080.890243]  [<ffffffff8107f9a7>] run_workqueue+0xc7/0x1a0
Dec 17 09:46:53 pujia-desktop kernel: [ 1080.890252]  [<ffffffff8107fb23>] worker_thread+0xa3/0x110
Dec 17 09:46:53 pujia-desktop kernel: [ 1080.890261]  [<ffffffff81084570>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x40
Dec 17 09:46:53 pujia-desktop kernel: [ 1080.890270]  [<ffffffff8107fa80>] ? worker_thread+0x0/0x110
Dec 17 09:46:53 pujia-desktop kernel: [ 1080.890278]  [<ffffffff810841f6>] kthread+0x96/0xa0
Dec 17 09:46:53 pujia-desktop kernel: [ 1080.890287]  [<ffffffff810131ea>] child_rip+0xa/0x20
Dec 17 09:46:53 pujia-desktop kernel: [ 1080.890296]  [<ffffffff81084160>] ? kthread+0x0/0xa0
Dec 17 09:46:53 pujia-desktop kernel: [ 1080.890303]  [<ffffffff810131e0>] ? child_rip+0x0/0x20
```

Comment: You seem to be missing some lines before each of these.  Look in `/var/log/kern.log` and see if there are better messages there perhaps?  I'm guessing that it's an Oops of somekind in the video driver (i915).

Comment: @DerfK, I've updated my post to add kern.log messages, could you take a look at it?

Comment: The community bot bumped this ancient question.  It looks like you found the answer and added it to the question.  Consider closing the loop on this by moving the answer to an answer post and accepted it.